# "Действующий и будущий регуляторы" - why not "действующие и будущие"?

Tags: грамматика, прилагательные, множественное-число

Действующий и будущий регуляторы отрасли — Минфин и ЦБ — согласовали проект реформы аудита в России.

This is from an article from kommersant.ru, why are the adjectives at the start in nominal singular form. Why aren't they `действующие` и `будущие`?

Comment: because those are different regulators

Comment: 1+1=2. Singular+Singular=Plural

Answer (score 13):

That's short for "действующий регулятор и будущий регулятор".

It's a perfectly valid and quite widely used construct in Russian. 
E.g. "a blue pencil and a green pencil" (синий карандаш и зелёный карандаш) can be shortened to "синий и зелёный карандаши" which I don't think is possible in English ("a blue and a green pencils"?). It's a kind of ellipsis where the noun is omitted after the first adjective. More examples to give you a better feel for the construct (they may sound contrived - that's because they are):

- Старший и младший братья = the elder brother and the younger brother.
- Новая и старая дороги = the new road and the old road.

Answer (score 4):

That's because Минфин is действующий регулятор отрасли and ЦБ is будущий регулятор отрасли.

**At this moment** Ministry of Finance is responsible for audit activity.
But Central bank will get this function from Ministry **in the future**.

Comment: So the answer is 'because you have only one at a time: one действующий and one будущий'

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that in this particular case the word `соответственно` is omitted, which is perfectly valid per se but it complicates understanding for a non-native speaker.

Think of this phrase like of:

> Действующий и будущий регуляторы отрасли — Минфин и ЦБ
>   ***соответственно*** — согласовали проект реформы аудита в России.

Which can be translated to something like:

> Present and soon-to-be industry controllers - Minfin and CB
>   ***accordingly***  ...