# Adjective in singular, noun in plural

Tags: грамматика

My Russian for beginners textbook has (it describes a shopping mall) the following sentence:

..., а также есть книжный и ювелирный магазины. (In case it's relevant, I can also provide the first part of the sentence.)

Why are "книжный" and "ювелирный" in the singular, but "магазины" in the plural? To confirm that it's not a mistake, I also googled for "книжный магазины" and got many results.

Thank you!

Comment: See https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/14998/2104

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we have **two shops** it's obvious we say **магазины**. But the shops are different.  One shop sells books, the other sells jewellery. In Russian we don't repeat one noun twice in the same sentence. You can't say книжный магазин и ювелирный магазин. The repeated noun is considered **redundant**,  so we unite the shops showing the quality separately. Since the quality adjectives belong to each shop we preserve them in the singular. That is logical. So as a result we have **книжный** (the first) **и ювелирный** (the second) **магазины**.

Comment: That's a great answer, thank you! So could I say "книжные и ювелирный магазины" when talking about three shops?

Comment: Yes, and also два книжных магазина и ювелирный.

Comment: What about 2 book shops and 5 jevellary stores?

Comment: Два книжных и пять ювелирных магазинов., or два книжных магазина и пять ювелирных.